# How do I add Serilog? Not have just Serilog, but have Serilog ALSO

Tags: blazor-server-side, serilog, serilog-aspnetcore

[All of the examples I have found](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore#serilogaspnetcore---) show adding Serilog using:

```
builder.Host.UseSerilog();
```

The problem is, that then makes Serilog the sole logging provider. There is:

```
builder.Logging.AddSerilog();
```

but that appears to do nothing.

How do I initialize Serilog so:

1. It is a logging provider, but does not clear out the other providers.
2. It gets all of its settings from appSettings.json